# Litecoin explorer that accepts M-prefixed segwit addresses?

Tags: litecoin, address-format

Just realized that the litecoin explorer I was using (blockcypher) doesn't allow me to input M-prefixed segwit addresses ([more info](https://blog.trezor.io/litecoins-new-p2sh-segwit-addresses-843633e3e707)).

Any other litecoin explorer that can do this?

Answer (score 2):

Seems this explorer works fine:

https://chainz.cryptoid.info/ltc